# New record for child grid not coming up in ax 2009

Tags: axapta

I have created a new grid in tabPage1 for ParentTable
and child grid for childTable in tabPage2.
After opening the form the data is getting displayed successfully but when i am in the tabpage2 and click on ctrl + N the new row is inserting a new row in the parent grid and not in the child grid.
How to insert a new row from the form for the child grid.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataSource` property of tabPage2 to the name of your child datasource.